# Find command can't find variable

Tags: bash, unix

```
echo $BASE_DIR
PROC_NM="ALLOC$REGION"
echo $PROC_NM
BASE_LOG_DIR=`find $BASE_DIR -filename "*$PROC_NM"`
echo $BASE_LOG_DIR
```

returns me:

```
"./scripts/checkout_dcc.sh" 113L, 2642C written
bash-3.2$  ./scripts/checkout_dcc.sh 
/opt/loghome/dream/rio/drop-copy-converter/
ALLOC_JPN
find: invalid predicate `-filename'
```

I've tried multiple different quotes for this, but for some reason find doesn't like me using the variable for the search dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `-filename` is not a valid predicate. You need `-name`, as specified in `man find`:

```
$ man find | grep -ce '-filename'
0
$ man find | grep -ce '-name'
15
```

Using a variable there will work as you expect:

```
find $BASE_DIR -name "*$PROC_NM"
```